# Why would someone use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) on a Buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have some existing code that is working with Buffer objects.

```
let dataObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Which seems to me like a no-op, ie it doesn't do anything. That's not correct though, as if I replace it with:

```
let dataObject = data;
```

The code fails. I've some some investigation and:

- `typeof data` is `object`
- `data.constructor.name` is `Object`
- data when logged is `<Buffer>... (long stream of bytes)`

**What does JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buffer)) do? Is there a better or clearer way of doing this?**

Answer (score 1):

The [`buf.toJSON()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tojson) method has a misleading name because it returns a JavaScript object, while JSON is actually a string data format. However, it returns a representation of the `Buffer` and the data it contains, so you can replace this:

```
let dataObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

With this cleaner code:

```
let dataObject = data.toJSON();
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my question, data.constructor.name is Object. I am trying to apply your answer but it does not work (`data.toJSON is not a function`). The confusion may be my fault.

Comment: I don't know what kind of object has `Object` as the constructor and displays `Buffer` when being logged (probably some kind of incomplete inheritance). Have you tried `Buffer.prototype.toJSON.call(data)`? If that doesn't work, you should add details on the prototype chain of the object you have, or the code that generates it.

Comment: Wouldn't the equivalent of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<Buffer>));` be `<Buffer>.toJSON()` directly instead of getting the `.data` property afterwards?

Comment: @Kaiido yes indeed I just tested it and noticed you were right. Fixed.